# Laptop (new) fails to start on half charged battery (hard shut off)

Tags: boot, power-management, laptop, battery

On a brand new Laptop, Ubuntu **fails to start** when on **half charged battery**. It otherwise works perfectly.

The symptoms are:

1. "bios" startup screen
2. grub menu shows for a few seconds
3. ubuntu logo shows briefly (2 sec)
4. laptop powers off abruptly

When restarting with plug on the wall, I see battery level is 47%. Unplugging the laptop works fine, and it will happely work on battery for a few hours...

I tried to `journalctl -b-1`, but I don't see any obvious problem, and I don't really know how to troubleshoot this...

Boot process goes to the point where:

```
[...]
mars 19 07:46:29 tibook systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch being skipped.
mars 19 07:46:29 tibook systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Plymouth Directory Watch.
mars 19 07:46:29 tibook systemd[1]: Reached target Local Encrypted Volumes.
mars 19 07:46:29 tibook systemd[1]: Mounted /var/log.
mars 19 07:46:29 tibook systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
mars 19 07:46:29 tibook systemd-journald[1380]: Time spent on flushing to /var/log/journal/13ef6951f0b3451c86ad31ff8146b19a is 7.516ms for 1007 entries.
```

I will of course give any useful information, but I don't know what to look for... (maybe ACPI ??)

Any pointer would be appreciated.

EDIT1: this does not happen everytime. I just did just boot while the battery was at 32%.

Thanks

Comment: Before anything else what you should be looking for is an uEFI update.

Comment: If it’s a hard shutdown before a boot sequence is even done, this sounds like a bad battery. If it cannot provide a base amount of power to the system, then the hardware will shut itself off rather than run with less voltage/amperage … 

Comment: @matigo in fact the boot sequence starts, and I get a journalctl log, so I hope it's not a faulty battery. Moreover, the battery works fine otherwise, except for this problem that does not happen everytime...

Comment: @ChanganAuto the laptop is new, I already have the latest BIOS/UEFI installed...

Comment: Do you use your notebook in cold places? Batteries tend to dislike temperatures below a certain threshold. This could explain the inconsistent failure rate. If it’s something in the OS, then you’ll see something written to `/var/log/syslog` a few microseconds before the failure (unless you’re getting “read-only file system” errors)

Comment: Try resetting the Power Manager... shut down laptop, hold down the POWER button for 30 seconds, retest for power off problem. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema that worked !! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @alci  Status please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and reset the [Power management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_management) (a feature that turns off the power or switches the system's components to a low-power state when inactive) this way:

Shutdown computer, hold down the Power button for ~30 seconds and reboot. Then retest for power off problem.

Comment: Do you have any source? [This sounds](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/12nyre/comment/c6wp6u9/) plausible too (also [here](https://www.geeksinphoenix.com/blog/post/2018/11/06/how-to-power-reset-your-laptop-computer)) Moreover, I couldn't find any reference to this procedure on the [respectable Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Power_management). The [HP Customer Support Knowledge Base](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/ish_1997208-1551050-16) seems reliable, but mention this more as a trick than as a Power management feature per se