# Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS does not boot when on laptop battery

Tags: boot, power-management, laptop, battery

When my laptop charger is unplugged, I can't boot Ubuntu. I can enter BIOS, so battery has charge. Ubuntu starts to load, but after few seconds it shuts down. Also I tried to load to login screen with charger plugged in, then unplug it and login, this also results in shutdown immidiately after login. But if I boot and login with plugged in charger and then unplug it, system works well. Battery should be fine, because I could load Windows 10 Live from USB flash with unplugged charger.

I tried to add [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1268804/ubuntu-20-04-does-not-boot-up-on-laptop-when-running-on-battery) two arguments, it temporarily solved the problem, but after one day the problem returns.

Laptop behavior is similiar to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398274/laptop-new-fails-to-start-on-half-charged-battery-hard-shut-off), I tried intended solution, but this did not work.

Comment: MSI and Ubuntu logos appear, then it shuts down